# TVS Apache RTR 160 - What Grade Engine Oil Should I Use?

Tags: motorcycle, oil, oil-change, apache-rtr, tvr

I bought a TVS Apache RTR 160 second hand. I want to know what grade engine oil should i use for my bike.

I was suggested to use 15W50. Is that a good choice. The bike has done almost 65000Kms.

Comment: 15W50 is a good choice, It is the best option for older bikes, get shell helix , its a bit pricey but it does the job best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this TVS service training presentation[TVS service training presentation](http://nexgenbikes.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Apache_RTR_160_manual.pdf?2fb5c5) they indicate using 4T motor oil.

4T is now the defacto name for motorcycle oil with many manufacturers (Mobile 1, Castrol, etc.).  4T is typically 10w40 with longer polymer chains to deal with the shearing of the transmission.  Since the gears of the transmission are lubricated with the engine oil, unlike cars, the gears can shear the molecules and reduced the effectiveness of oil more rapidly.

So, 4T Motorcycle Engine Oil, 10w40 is what the manufacturer recommends.  TVS also have their own 'braned' oil that they use in their dealerships.

Comment: Hi,
I agree with your thoughts, but I have observed that bike vibrates more when I use 10W40 as compared to 15W50.

The above behaviour is observed only during long drives. 70-100KM

Comment: @tushar  What are you using to measure the vibration?

Comment: I have not used any tool as such. I just feel it more on the foot peg.

Comment: Is there any tool or instrument to measure?

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of searching - I've found that nowhere in the manuals of warranty the engine oil grade is mentioned, i've also looked thru several forums where 10w40 to 20w40 grade of oil is recommended for TVS APACHE RTR 160 bikes by expert bikers and mechanics alike.

EDIT :

I have found the manual - which seems to be a recent upload by TVS motor. Their collaboration with BMW seems to be bringing a lot of improvement and best practices, both to bikes, service and sales, as well as customer relations.

The oil you are supposed to use for the Apache series is TVS TRU4 Synthetic or TVS TRU4 premium SAE 10w30 API-SL JASO MA2 standard oil.

[image: The Page of the Owners manual with a footnote on the ideal engine oil]

You can find it on page 01 of this document : 
[Apache 160 Hyper Edge Owners Manual](https://www.tvsmotor.com/pdf/Manuals-Apache-RTR-160-NEW.pdf)

Do let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: There is this document that indicates using 4T.   http://nexgenbikes.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Apache_RTR_160_manual.pdf?2fb5c5

Comment: @DucatiKiller i have found the owners manual for this one. Can you please take a look and update the official answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching a lot about engine oils and chekced with my local service center as well. I finalized below 2 options:

a. Motul 7100 4T Fully Synthetic 10W-40
b. Shell Advance Ultra 10W40 Fully Synthetic

They perform much better when it comes to reducing vibrations and shifts in the bike.

Answer (score -1):

15w50 you can use for Apache rtr 160.
It's recommended and bike is very smooth with it.

Comment: Do you have documentation to support this recommendation you can link to?